# Reduce the output current from a stepper driver

Tags: stepper-motor, stepper-driver

I have to control 2 stepper motors with a single driver (multiplexing one at a time) and both motors are different, one 1.7A and the other 0.4A, if I set the current to 1.7A the 0.4A motor can burn out. Is it possible to put resistors at the output of the driver to reduce the current? How could I calculate it?
[image]

edited: the motors are

1.7A=17HS4401S, resistance per phase: 1.5 ohm

0.4A=JK42HS34-0404, resistance per phase: 30 ohm

Comment: The motors may already have different resistances. Add this info to the question.

Comment: I am confused. How can you "***set the current to 2A?***

Comment: @BrianDrummond edited

Comment: @tlfong01 the driver (a4988, is the most popular) have a potentiometer and you able to set current up to 2A

Comment: @Ricardo Casimiro, I vaguely remember that for either microstepping or non-microstepping step motor drivers, I don't need to "set the current". I always thought that the current the driver drives the motor is "set" or "decided" by Ohm's Law, less motor coil resistance means more driving current, with the limit of the max current specified by the driver. Of course I assume your power supply has a constant voltage.

Comment: I think you're going to have to use two different A4988 modules if you need to have two different motor current limits set.  This module has only the onboard potentiometer to set the max current and there is no means provided to set it programmatically or from another input.

Comment: In other words, the motor current is "set" by the Vmot according to Ohm's Law, where Imot = Vmot / Rmot. So one solution is mux the power supply voltage at the same time.

Comment: And multiplexing or demultiplexing two PSUs to one A4988 Vmot input is not that complicated, eg, you can use two P-Channel MOSFETs, one to switch PSU1, another to switch PSU2. But it is not worth your time, because A4988 is so dirt cheap. :)

Comment: I must apologize that I used a couple of stepper motor drivers, but never A4988. So my comments and suggestion might be nonsense to A4988. You mentioned an "***on board pot***" which I think is ***for over current protection***, not for operating current setting.

Comment: Ah, you remind me one thing. I did once played with the big driver similar to the following: MP425 motor driver: https://nl.aliexpress.com/item/4001010044997.html?spm=a2g0o.search0302.0.0.12a88a36EIueeZ&algo_pvid=a7014612-814e-4b7e-9b82-5283382ca2f5&algo_expid=a7014612-814e-4b7e-9b82-5283382ca2f5-2&btsid=0bb0624216140036430962038e22e6&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_ /to continue, ...

Comment: For this kind of industrial grade driver, there is a DSP (Digital Signal Processor) and current sensor circuits that can do the fine "micro stepping", by very quickly switching on and off the motor coil current to set the peak and rms voltage, for max efficiency and performance. I must again apologize that I am just scratching the surface of microstepping knowledge, so no guarantee that I am not talking nonsense. :) Ah, bed time, See you later. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible if you have some high wattage resistors. Adjust your VMOT to give you the proper current through the 0.4V motor and rely on the internal chopper to give you the proper current in the 1.7A motor. Keep in mind that if you start chopping the output to control the current through the 1.7A motor, you will effectively decrease the applied voltage on the 0.4A motor so you'll have to get the resistances just right if you want to run both motors at their maximum current. If you match the motor current exactly, you will not be chopping at low speeds, but you may not be able to achieve high speeds with good torque because motor inductance is going to start dominating the current response and you'll have no way to control it. It would be significantly better and possibly cheaper to run with two separate drivers. High power resistors aren't cheap. You'll probably need 25W resistors to get the job done without starting a fire. If you drive the motors in series, you could use 7 Ohm resistors across the 0.4A motor windings. Then you need to drive VMOT with 15V. I don't think you'll want to try to microstep in any of these configurations.